# Responsive "table"

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have an HTML table that is too wide for small screens. I am trying to get rid of this table and use lists and divs to have a more responsive design.

Here is my HTML I came up with:

```
<ul>
    <li class="fixture">
        <div class="fixture-date">01/09/2014 20:00</div>
        <div class="fixture-details">
            <div class="home-team">Team A</div>
            <div class="result">Result</div>
            <div class="away-team">Team B</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="forecasts">
            <li class="player-forecast">
                <div class="player">Player 1</div>
                <div class="forecast">Forecast</div>
                <div class="score">3.0</div>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I want it to look like this on small screens:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
| 01/09/2014                                         |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|             Team A |  Result  | Team B             |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|    Player 1        | Forecast |               3.0  |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|    Player 2        | Forecast |               0.0  |
```

and like this on wide screens:

```
                                                  |    Player 1    |    Player 2    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 01/09/2014 |      Team A | Result | Team B      | Forecast | 3.0 | Forecast | 0.0 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 01/09/2014 |      Team C | Result | Team D      | Forecast | 1.0 | Forecast | 2.0 |
```

I have set up a fiddle with what I have achieved so far: http://jsfiddle.net/vwanr2gx/

I have not found a way to put all the "cells" for a fixture on the same row and keep the same width for the "cells" in the same "column". I cannot hard-code the width of the cells for teams as I don't know the content (user-generated).

I have tried to use css tables, but since I have nested divs, it automatically creates new rows (see fiddle).

How can I achieve that (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you found a solution for this question, but here is one that I developed. These are the details:

- Kept your HTML code (replaced some `ul`/`li` tags with `div`, but it probably will work with your lists just making small changes in the styles), and changed the CSS depending on the media width.
- If it's a "big display", then only the first row of player names will be displayed.
- `float:left`, `float:left`, `float:left`...

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yuL0pvgt/1/. And this is the CSS code that I used:

```
* {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:12px;
}
#mytable {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.fixture {
    display:table-row;
}
.fixture-date {
    display:block;
}
.fixture-details {
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
.fixture-details .home-team {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    text-align:right;
}
.fixture-details .result {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
}
.fixture-details .away-team {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    text-align:left;
}
.forecasts {
    display:block;
}
.forecasts .player-forecast {
    display:block;
}
.forecasts .player-forecast .player {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    text-align:left;
}
.forecasts .player-forecast .forecast {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
}
.forecasts .player-forecast .score {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    text-align:right;
}
@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
    .fixture {
        vertical-align:bottom;
        height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
        width:100%;
    }
    .fixture-date {
        display:inline-block;
        width:20%;
        height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    .fixture-details {
        display:inline-block;
        width:35%;
    }
    .forecasts {
        display:inline-block;
        width:45%;
        height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    .forecasts .player-forecast {
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
        width:33.33%;
        line-height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    .forecasts .player-forecast .player {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .forecasts .player-forecast .forecast {
        width:50%;
    }
    .forecasts .player-forecast .score {
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .fixture:not(:first-child) .player {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Was this the type of solution that you were looking for?

Some challenges/things-left-to-do with this solution:

- Fixing the spaces: you may notice that there's some blank space between the rows (vertically), this can be fixed using `display:inline-block`, but then you'd have to deal with blank space horizontally (there are a few posts about how to fix it on stackoverflow)
- The solution is specific for 3 players (notice the `.forecasts .player-forecast { width:33.33%; }`, this 33.33% should be changed to 100 / number_of_players for optimal visualization).
- You will need to adjust the widths so they match your needs.

Comment: It did help, especially with the headers. The issues with your solution is that you set the width on a lot of "cells" and that's not I want to do (I don't know the number of players and the length of the team names). But, I know the content of other cells so I can work from that. Using your ideas and what I have found after posting this question, I have came up with a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/dchaib/vwanr2gx/2/. It still needs comestic work, but I think it is the behaviour I want.

Comment: I used percentages to make it generic. You could use directly a value for some columns and `calc()` to calculate the width for some others, to make it look cleaner (as you do in your jsfiddle, although the numbers don't seem right).

Comment: About not knowing the number of players, right now I can't think of a way of setting a standard width that will fit all number of players and occupy 100% of the width. That seems to be a problem that you'd have all the time. If you want all the player columns to have the same width, you'll probably need to adjust it when you generate the table (at that time you'll know) or via JavaScript/jQuery after it was generated.

Comment: The numbers don't seem right for wider screens, but I think the table-cell display takes over anyway. I agree with you that occupying 100% of the width is tricky, especially if there are a great number of players... I guess I'll simply try to pin the fist columns to left allow some scrolling for the rest as a backup solution.

Comment: I mark this answer as accepted as it helped me achieve what I wanted, especially for the headers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to build smarter tables, not using the  tag, but using css3 display properties and classes. Thats my way of doing responsive tables.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td"></div>
        <div class="td"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Amd your css should be like this:

```
.table { display: table; }
.tr { display: table-row; }
.td { display: table-cell; }
```

So basically on the resolution you want your table to be 'responsive' you just say that you want your table-cells ( .td ) to be

```
.td {display: block; }
```

and you will have everything aligned perfectly!
Here is live demo (set resolution to higher and see for yourself:) http://jsfiddle.net/Cowwando/2jkm108u/
Regards!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried this and it doesn't work as I want. I need some rowspan for the "fixture-date" row as the text can be longer than the "team-home" cell and I don't want it to offset everything.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the solution you're looking for, but if you don't mind DIVs instead of TABLE, you could try and use flexbox. This could give you some inspiration: [Really Responsive Tables using Flexbox](https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx)

Comment: is it possible to make expandable tables with flexbox?